# Webpack, less-loader - Unexpected token - Why?

Tags: javascript, less, webpack

I'm using Webpack (in a Windows environment) and I'm trying to use `less-loader` and `extract-text-webpack-plugin` to generate a css file. I have `less`, `webpack-core` and `webpack` also in my `node_modules` folder.

In my app I use:

```
require('./index.less');
```

My Webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './app/index.jsx'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/public'),
        filename: "js/app.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            include: path.join(__dirname, '/app'),
            exclude: path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules'),
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
                plugins: ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
            }
        },{
            test: /\.(css|less)$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("css-loader", "less-loader")
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('css/app.css')
    ]
};
```

From my understanding, this should mean that when Webpack comes across my `index.less` file, it uses `less-loader` first to generate CSS, then `css-loader` to drop the contents into the export file (`css/app.css` in this case).

This is the error I'm getting:

> ERROR in ./app/index.less
>
> Module build failed: ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: c:\node\react2\node_modules\less-loader\index.js!c:\node\react2\app\index.less Line 1: Unexpected token {
>
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>
> | body { |   color: #333; |   background-color: #f5f5f5;
>       at DependenciesBlock. (c:\node\react2\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:113:20)
>       at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (c:\node\react2\node_modules\webpack-core\lib\NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
>       at nextLoader (c:\node\react2\node_modules\webpack-core\lib\NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
>       at c:\node\react2\node_modules\webpack-core\lib\NormalModuleMixin.js:292:15
>       at context.callback (c:\node\react2\node_modules\webpack-core\lib\NormalModuleMixin.js:148:14)
>       at c:\node\react2\node_modules\less-loader\index.js:70:3
>       at c:\node\react2\node_modules\less\lib\less\render.js:35:17
>       at c:\node\react2\node_modules\less\lib\less\parse.js:63:17
>       at Object.finish [as _finish] (c:\node\react2\node_modules\less\lib\less\parser\parser.js:183:28)
>       at Object.ImportVisitor._onSequencerEmpty (c:\node\react2\node_modules\less\lib\less\visitors\import-visitor.js:35:14)
>       at ImportSequencer.tryRun (c:\node\react2\node_modules\less\lib\less\visitors\import-sequencer.js:50:14)
>       at Object.ImportVisitor.run (c:\node\react2\node_modules\less\lib\less\visitors\import-visitor.js:29:25)
>       at Object.Parser.parse (c:\node\react2\node_modules\less\lib\less\parser\parser.js:189:22)
>       at Object.parse (c:\node\react2\node_modules\less\lib\less\parse.js:61:18)
>       at Object.render (c:\node\react2\node_modules\less\lib\less\render.js:25:18)
>       at Object.module.exports (c:\node\react2\node_modules\less-loader\index.js:62:7)

So the `less-loader` has a problem at line 1. My LESS code is very simple:

```
body {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2% 5%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 1em;
    p {
        margin: 0 0 1em 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

How can the `less-loader` have a problem with `body {}`..?

**UPDATE**: If I add `style-loader` like this: `ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader", "less-loader")`, the error goes away, but the resulting CSS file contains LESS - as in - the nesting is still there: `body { p {} }` instead of `body {} body p {}`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was reviewing this page: https://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html in the excellent Webpack docs :-).

It shows: `ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader!less-loader")`.

I tried this and it works! I get plain CSS in the output file.

I wasn't using `ExtractTextPlugin.extract()` correctly. The [`extract-text-webpack-plugin` docs](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin) show that the first param is optional (the loader(s) that should be used when the css is not extracted), and the second param is loader string (the loader(s) that should be used for converting the resource to a css exporting module).

Comment: This just convinces me that someone needs to make a performant and better documented clone of webpack. the *second* argument is the one that's necessary and the first argument is the fallback loader? that makes zero sense.

Comment: The syntax has changed again, which the doc-link also shows:

      use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: "css-loader!less-loader"
      })